# Detect .NET Framework features and WCF Services

Tags: c#, .net, iis

[IIS Roles and Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0Mhw.png)

I'm trying to detect the .NET Framework features and WCF Services above. Do these map to anything in the registry? Or could anyone point me in the direction to where/how I could detect that these features are installed on a system?

I was able to find the Roles (previous screen) in the registry so I'm sure the Features are somewhere close.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the powershell. Windows server have the module `Get-WindowsFeature` that you can use to get installed features. See below PS script to get WCF and .Net feature installed:

```
Get-WindowsFeature | where {$_.installed -eq $true -and ($_.displayname -like "*WCF*" -or $_.displayname -like ".Net*")} | select displayname, name, installed
```